# Calculate the Discount Fitness Price (30%, 20% and 15% Off)

Tags: c++, function, math, mathematical-optimization, discount

## User - Defined Functions

The cost to become a member of a fitness center is as follows:

- The senior citizens discount is 30%.
- If the membership is bought and paid for 12 or more months, the discount is 15%
- If more than five personal training sessions are bought and paid for, the discount on each session is 20%.

Write a menu-driven program that determines the cost of a new membership. Your program must contain a function that displays the general information about the fitness center and its charges, a function to get all of the necessary information to determine the membership cost, and a function to determine the membership cost. Use appropriate parameters to pass information in and out of a function. (Do not use any global variables.)

**My codes:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// program constants

void setPrices(double&, double&);
void getInfo(bool&, bool&, bool&, int&, int&);
double membershipCost(double, int, double, int, bool, bool, bool);

void displayCenterInfo();


int main()
{
    bool seniorCitizen;
    bool boughtFiveOrMoreSessions;
    bool paidTwelveOrMoreMonths;

    int numberOfMembershipMonths;
    int numberOfPersonalTrainingSessions;
    double regularMembershipChargesPerMonth;
    double costOfOnePersonalTrainingSession;

    double memberCost;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    displayCenterInfo();

    cout << endl;

    setPrices(regularMembershipChargesPerMonth, costOfOnePersonalTrainingSession);

    getInfo(seniorCitizen, boughtFiveOrMoreSessions, paidTwelveOrMoreMonths, numberOfMembershipMonths, numberOfPersonalTrainingSessions);

    // cal getInfo
    memberCost = membershipCost(regularMembershipChargesPerMonth, numberOfMembershipMonths, costOfOnePersonalTrainingSession,
        numberOfPersonalTrainingSessions, seniorCitizen, boughtFiveOrMoreSessions, paidTwelveOrMoreMonths);

    cout << "$" << memberCost;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void displayCenterInfo()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Stay Healty and Fit center." << endl;
    cout << "This program determines the cost of a new membership." << endl;
    cout << "If you are a senior citizen, then the discount is 30% of "
        << "of the regular membership price." << endl;
    cout << "If you buy membership for twelve months and pay today, the "
        << "discount is 15%." << endl;
    cout << "If you buy and pay for 6 or more personal training session today, "
        << "the discount on each session is 20%." << endl;
}

void setPrices(double& regMemPrice, double& personalTrSesCost)
{

    cout << "Please enter the cost of regular Membership per month: " << endl;
    cin >> regMemPrice;

    cout << "Please enter the cost of one personal traning session: " << endl;
    cin >> personalTrSesCost;

}

void getInfo(bool& senCitizen, bool& bFiveOrMoreSess, bool& paidTwMnth,
    int& nOfMonths, int& nOfPersonalTrSess)
{
    //Senior Verification
    char userInputSenior;
    cout << "Are you Senior? Please enter 'Y' or 'N': ";
    cin >> userInputSenior;

    if (userInputSenior == 'y' && userInputSenior == 'Y')
    {
        senCitizen = true;
    }
    else
        senCitizen = false;

    cout << endl;


    //Number of personal training session.
    cout << "Enter the number of personal training sessions bought: ";
    cin >> nOfPersonalTrSess;

    if (nOfPersonalTrSess >= 5)
    {
        bFiveOrMoreSess = true;
    }
    else
        bFiveOrMoreSess = false;

    cout << endl;


    //Number of months
    cout << "Enter the number of months you are paying for: ";
    cin >> nOfMonths;

    if (nOfMonths >= 12)
    {
        paidTwMnth = true;
    }
    else
        paidTwMnth = false;

}

double membershipCost(double regMemPricePerMth, int nOfMonths,
    double personalTrSesCost, int nOfPersonalTrSess,
    bool senCitizen, bool bFiveOrMoreSess, bool paidTwMnth)
{
    double finalMembershipCost, finalSessionCost;


    //Session Discount
    if (bFiveOrMoreSess)
    {
        personalTrSesCost = personalTrSesCost * 0.8;
    }
    else
    {
        personalTrSesCost = personalTrSesCost;
    }


    //Month Discount
    if (paidTwMnth)
    {
        regMemPricePerMth = regMemPricePerMth * 0.85;
    }
    else
    {
        regMemPricePerMth = regMemPricePerMth;
    }


    finalMembershipCost = regMemPricePerMth * nOfMonths;
    finalSessionCost = personalTrSesCost * nOfPersonalTrSess;

    // Check if Senior Citizen Discount Applies
    if (senCitizen) {
        return (finalMembershipCost * 0.7) + finalSessionCost ;
    }
    else {
        return finalMembershipCost + finalSessionCost;
    }

}
```

My Test Result

[image: My Test Result]

An error occurs on "*Senior Citizen Discount*".

[image: The "*Senior Citizen Discount*" error]

**Green color** - My output.

**Red color** - Its output (**Correct Answer**).

I don't know how to get that answer (**$2260.00**) with my code. I have checked many times and I couldn't solve the problem. Please help me!

Comment: Discount double check? This is not a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with an emphasis on _minimal_.

Comment: @JustinRandall I have checked many times. Not only me, my friend and my tutor also checked it, but no one seems can solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: You should use a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an or-Statement for detecting if its a senior citizen:

```
if (userInputSenior == 'y' || userInputSenior == 'Y')
```

BTW: You have another small bug when calculating the discount for personal lessons, you only get a discount for *more than 5 sessions*, so the corresponding if-statement should be

```
(nOfPersonalTrSess > 5)
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed it. However, I still cannot solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, it does solve your problem.  With the following inputs (along with MarcusS suggested fix) I get the correct answer of $2260.00.  cost per month=1100, cost of one session=150, senior discount=true, sessions bought=6, months purchased=2

Comment: @DavidLe You are welcome! Was my answer correct? Or did you actually have another problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys so much, I **solved** my problem!

Here is my complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// program constants

void setPrices(double&, double&);
void getInfo(bool&, bool&, bool&, int&, int&);
double membershipCost(double, int, double, int, bool, bool, bool);

void displayCenterInfo();


int main()
{
    bool seniorCitizen;
    bool boughtSixOrMoreSessions;
    bool paidTwelveOrMoreMonths;

    int numberOfMembershipMonths;
    int numberOfPersonalTrainingSessions;
    double regularMembershipChargesPerMonth;
    double costOfOnePersonalTrainingSession;

    double memberCost;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    displayCenterInfo();

    cout << endl;

    setPrices(regularMembershipChargesPerMonth, costOfOnePersonalTrainingSession);

    getInfo(seniorCitizen, boughtSixOrMoreSessions, paidTwelveOrMoreMonths, numberOfMembershipMonths, numberOfPersonalTrainingSessions);

    // cal getInfo
    memberCost = membershipCost(regularMembershipChargesPerMonth, numberOfMembershipMonths, costOfOnePersonalTrainingSession,
        numberOfPersonalTrainingSessions, seniorCitizen, boughtSixOrMoreSessions, paidTwelveOrMoreMonths);

    cout << "$" << memberCost;

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void displayCenterInfo()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Stay Healty and Fit center." << endl;
    cout << "This program determines the cost of a new membership." << endl;
    cout << "If you are a senior citizen, then the discount is 30% of "
        << "of the regular membership price." << endl;
    cout << "If you buy membership for twelve months and pay today, the "
        << "discount is 15%." << endl;
    cout << "If you buy and pay for 6 or more personal training session today, "
        << "the discount on each session is 20%." << endl;
}

void setPrices(double& regMemPrice, double& personalTrSesCost)
{

    cout << "Please enter the cost of regular Membership per month: " << endl;
    cin >> regMemPrice;

    cout << "Please enter the cost of one personal traning session: " << endl;
    cin >> personalTrSesCost;

}

void getInfo(bool& senCitizen, bool& bSixOrMoreSess, bool& paidTwMnth,
    int& nOfMonths, int& nOfPersonalTrSess)
{
    //Senior Verification
    char userInputSenior;
    cout << "Are you Senior? Please enter 'Y' or 'N': ";
    cin >> userInputSenior;

    if (userInputSenior == 'y' || userInputSenior == 'Y')
    {
        senCitizen = true;
    }
    else
        senCitizen = false;

    cout << endl;


    //Number of personal training session.
    cout << "Enter the number of personal training sessions bought: ";
    cin >> nOfPersonalTrSess;

    if (nOfPersonalTrSess > 5)
    {
        bSixOrMoreSess = true;
    }
    else
        bSixOrMoreSess = false;

    cout << endl;


    //Number of months
    cout << "Enter the number of months you are paying for: ";
    cin >> nOfMonths;

    if (nOfMonths >= 12)
    {
        paidTwMnth = true;
    }
    else
        paidTwMnth = false;

}

double membershipCost(double regMemPricePerMth, int nOfMonths,
    double personalTrSesCost, int nOfPersonalTrSess,
    bool senCitizen, bool bSixOrMoreSess, bool paidTwMnth)
{
    double finalMembershipCost, finalSessionCost;


    //Session Discount
    if (bSixOrMoreSess)
    {
        personalTrSesCost = (personalTrSesCost * 0.8);

    }
    else
    {
        personalTrSesCost = personalTrSesCost;

    }


    //Month Discount
    if (paidTwMnth)
    {
        regMemPricePerMth = regMemPricePerMth * 0.85;
    }
    else
    {
        regMemPricePerMth = regMemPricePerMth;
    }

    finalMembershipCost = regMemPricePerMth * nOfMonths;
    finalSessionCost = personalTrSesCost * nOfPersonalTrSess;


    // Check if Senior Citizen Discount Applies
    if (senCitizen) {
        return (finalMembershipCost * 0.7) + finalSessionCost;
    }
    else {
        return finalMembershipCost + finalSessionCost;
    }


}
```